# Why does Huawei Honor 6 show something other on screen when I put a magnet on it?

Tags: magnetometer, huawei-honor-6

Normal mode:

[image: normal mode]

Magnet mode:

[image: magnet mode 1][image: magnet mode 2]

This pops up regardless of lock screen status. If I add and remove the magnet while unlocked, it does not get locked. There is also third screen with music controls when music app is running.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does it act this way on every screen, or just a lock screen?  Every magnet or just this magnet?

Comment: Any magnet, just the lock screen.

Comment: Interesting.  Usually magnets are used in holsters to automatically lock the device *and turn off the screen*, but that's the same effect as what's happening here.

Comment: Correction: this pops up regardless of lock screen status. If I add and remove the magnet while unlocked, it does not get locked. There is also third screen with music controls when music app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature to display useful info and interact with it when you're using magnetic case for Huawei Honor 6. Searching for ["Huawei Honor 6 magnetic case"](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=huawei+honor+6+magnetic+case&tbm=isch) will show how it's supposed to be used:

[image: huawei honor 6 magnetic case]

<sup>(Image courtesy of Lelong.my)</sup>

From what I researched, most of Honor 6's magnetic cases have small cut-in on the front-right side where you can touch the screen to interact with the phone while the case is closed.

Comment: How do I turn it off? Does it increase the attack surface if I want to secure my device?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where my research ended. I didn't find anything about that and I don't have both the device and the case, so I can't experiment with it further.